# apache - redirect suddomain to main domain

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, redirect, subdomain

I rebuilt my old site. There was a subdomain to that old site: `forum.example.com`. Now, it does not exist anymore. A person who accesses my site using `forum.example.com` should be redirected to `example.com`.

My `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

If the host is not `example.com`, redirect to `example.com`. Shouldn't `forum.example.com` fit in the condition?

Now for the optional part of the question, if someone could explain to me the rule above, it would be great.

Here's what I understand in the above rule:

If the host is NOT `example.com` (`!^example.com$`)
redirect to `http://example.com`.

What I don't understand is the first part of the rule regex: `^(.*)$`, and then the reference to it (`$1`). How come matching everything can be put as the requested file path? Wouldn't it do something like this?

```
http://example.com/http://www.example.com/[requested file]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

The above code looks at the HTTP host of the connecting browser. Note that .htaccess can only work on a request that can reach the webserver. This will work for `forum.example.com`, but only if `forum.example.com` actually loads the content in the directory that the .htaccess file resides in. If you do not have the DNS records set up (for example, a `*` A record or a `forum` A record) then it will not even go to the site at all, because the DNS is invalid. Also, Apache must be set up to load the site for that VirtualHost. So it must be listed in the Apache configuration as well before .htaccess can forward the URL as specified.

For your second question, in the `RewriteRule` part `^(.*)$`, this only matches the file that is accessed off the server. The `RewriteCond` part only applies the rule on certain hostnames, then `^(.*)$` specifies that any request follow the rewrite rules.

So the above .htaccess code will apply for all requests after the `/` if the host does not equal `example.com`.

Let me know if you need any further explanation.

Comment: It does answer a lot of my questions.

Thanks a lot for your time. 

I need 15 rep to vote you up, so sorry, I can't right now.